# Contents of Stack Frame in Java

Tags: java, jvm, vm-implementation

It is evident from Java Virtual Machine Implementation (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/index.html) that stack frame present on heap which stores the method's runtime data. But what are the contents of stack frame in java and how the stack frame is organized to store values of local variables and intermediate results. How is the data structure organized.

Comment: What data structure do you mean? It's just a bunch of contiguous memory cells. Look at the bytecode, and you'll understand.

Comment: how can I look into bytecodes, I mean binary data, is there a tool to look into it.

Comment: According to Section `2.5.2` of JVM Specification Java SE 8 Edition: *The memory for a Java Virtual Machine stack does not need to be contiguous* [Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.2).

Answer (score 5):

First of all, stack frame is part of JVM stack, not Heap [JVM memory is divided in 5 parts: Method Area, Heap, Stack, PC Register and Native Memory.]

To answer your question, stack frame is divided into three parts: local variable array, frame data and operand stack. Refer to the following link for detailed info:
http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/jvm8.html

Comment: According to Section `2.5.2` of JVM Specification Java SE 8 Edition: *Because the Java Virtual Machine stack is never manipulated directly except to push and pop frames, frames may be heap allocated* [Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.2).