# Where does the reference to the primitive variable get stored in java?

Tags: java, memory-management, heap-memory, stack-memory

I know that primitive values are stored in stack and non primitive values are stored in heap. As far as I know the stack also contains reference to the non primitive values. Now my doubt is where do we store reference to the primitives? i.e, for example,

```
int a=10;
```

Now the value 10 gets stored in stack as far as I know, but my question is where does the value `a` get stored?

Also please suggest some good resources to learn memory management in Java. I've read tons of stuff online, but none of them are clear to me.

Comment: There is no value "a". It is just an offset into the stack (if `a` is a local variable) or into the object's memory (if `a` is a field.) See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20441256/contents-of-stack-frame-in-java. "none of them are clear to me" -- in what way? You'll need to ask specific questions.

Comment: And primitive valuse can be stored in the heap, when they are a field of a class, or an array element.

Comment: Not all primitives are stored on the stack.  If a primitive is part of an object, it will be on the heap with the rest of the object.

Comment: Also, the name of the variable (`"a"` in your case) isn't really part of the executing program; so I wouldn't expect it to get stored in any place that's accessible to the runtime.

Comment: @tgdavies I didn't go into specifics regarding the last part, cause that  wasn't my question. My question is whats above that. I just asked you guys to suggest some resources, so I can better understand the topic.

Comment: It's unclear whether your declaration is a local variable or a field. If it's a field you can find the name in the class file: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.5

Comment: @tgdavies What if its a local variable? The reference variable "a" has to get stored somewhere right? Where does it get stored?

Comment: The compiler just knows that that value is at some particular offset on the stack, and uses that offset when the variable is accessed.

Comment: i.e. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.iload (although I'm not certain what you're thinking of when you say "reference variable")

Comment: There is no 'reference variable `a`'. `a` *is* an *integer* variable. The compiler knows its offset in the current stack frame if local, or where it is in the containing object if on the heap. Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 5):

So it's not correct say that primitives are stored (only) on the stack and references stored (only) on the heap.  First, some code:

```
public static main( String args... ) {
  Widget w = new Widget();
}

class Widget {
   private int i = 10;
   private String name = "FooBar";
}
```

So in `main`, the reference `w` is stored (canonically) on the stack.  The **instance** the reference points to is stored on the heap.

Within that instance, there's a variable `i` that's stored on the heap, because it's part of the `Widget` instance.  There's also a reference to another object, `name` that points to a second object instance `"FooBar"` that is also stored on the heap.

So here is an example of a reference `w` on the stack, and a reference `name` on the heap.  They can be stored in either location.

Ditto with primitives. I think you understand how primitives get stored on the stack.  So I had `Widget` store a primitive on the heap to show how that works.

(All that said, the "stack" can be kept on the heap, if the compiler or JVM/OS really want to, and small objects can be allocated on the stack for speed, so it's really a bit more complicated.  But ignoring tricky stuff, normally we say that the stack and the heap work like above.)

**Also please suggest some good resources to learn memory management in Java.**  Take a systems programming course or two at your university (typically one on compilers/linkers and one on "how to write an operating system").  If you're not at a university, go to university.  Some stuff they don't teach by reading some random Wordpress blog.

**where does the value "a" get stored?** "a" is just a label used by the source text, it gets effectively erased at runtime.  The compiler (the runtime byte codes or assembly language) just uses a number to refer to the variable, that number is just the offset (or position) on the stack.  It's just like accessing an array of numbers.  The stack is like an int array, `stack = new int[100]` or whatever, and each local variable is just a number, an offset, into that array.  This includes references too, which are stored at an offset in the stack and themselves just "point" to heap memory by being the address (as a number) of the location in memory of the object.  It gets more complicated because the stack can also have bytes and char (16 bits) and long, but the CPU and assembly language can handle that fine.

Comment: Hey so my question is...if in the main function we have a local variable called as "a" with a value of 10. The values 10 gets stored in stack right. Now where does the value "a" get stored?

Comment: @CypherZ There is no 'value `a`', other than the piece of memory holding the 10. You are asking about something that doesn't exist.

Comment: The compiler knows that it needs e. g. 32 bit to store a local variable `int a`, so it reserves 32 bit on the stack for this variable. The compiler knows the offset of this value on the stack and uses this offset whenever the source code accesses `a`. The bytecode doesn't contain a variable `a` anymore, it deals with addresses.

Comment: The other commenters are correct, the "a" is just a label in the source text, it gets erased at runtime and replaced with just a number, its position in the stack. @CypherZ